# Nuxt generate with vuex and multi-language site

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex, nuxt-i18n

I am currently building my first (statically generated) website with nuxt and a headless Wordpress as CMS. I am also using the module `nuxt-i18n` for multi-language support: German (default) and English.

**The setup**

To fetch data from the multi-language Wordpress I use the module `wp-nuxt` and then store the data from the CMS in thes `vuex` store. Dependent on the client browser language or when the language is changed by the user manually, the endpoint of `$wp` (`wp-nuxt`) is changed, so the appropiate content will be fetched and stored in the store.

Now, on `NuxtServerInit()` some basic data is fetched from the CMS for the locale defined by the route (e.g. `http://myserver/en/news` will fetch basic data from the english CMS endpoint `http://wphost/mycms/en/wp-json/wp/v2/...`, see `/en/` in endpoint). For each layout/page further content is fetched via `asyncData()` and `fetch()`, also, of course, for the current locale.

**The problem**

This works fine, as long nuxt is ran via `nuxt dev`. If the locale is switched by the user, the fetches for the other locale will be handled by `asyncData()` and `fetch()` on the client.

`nuxt generate` works also for the locale the site was first loaded with, however has troubles when switching locales: The data is not found in the store.

My guess is: On `generate` nuxt is calling `nuxtServerInit()`, `asyncData()` and `fetch()` for each route. This will fill the store of each route with the routes locale data. For DE-Routes (e.g. `myserver/impressum`)  german content, for EN-routes (e.g. `myserver/en/site-notice`) english content. But if the locale is changed by the user, the stores of these routes only contain content for the current locale and `asyncData()` and `fetch()` won't be called to fill the store (of course, this is by design of `generate`).

Consequently, it seems to me that nuxt is storing different "vuex store instances" for the different routes and cannot switch to the store on user initiated locale switch.

**Possible workarounds**

There are a few simple workarounds I already tried and seem to solve the issue but are far from perfect:

1. Trigger a reload on language switch, so the site is realoaded and nuxt is loading the store for the route with the correct locale. - I don't like it, it feels hacky.
2. Fill the store via `nuxtServerInit()` with data of both languages, by fetching against both CMS endpoints. - I don't like it either, it feels hacky and although it may work for two languages this has huge overhead, the more content the CMS has.

I hope I was able to describe the problem appropriately. Is there something I am missing? I haven't found anything on this, so far. I would appreciate if you have any thoughts on that.

Thanks,
Valentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause of the problem**

I finally got to the source of the issue. I will share my misconceptions with you so it might help someone with similar setup.

So first of all, on `generate` saves the results of the `nuxtServerInit()` of the store and the `asyncData()` and `fetch()` of the layout and page components for each route in a `payload.js` file to simulate the API calls on the generated static site (https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static/#crazy-fast-static-applications).

When writing the original post, I did two things, which made nuxt not store the whole payload of the `fetch()` method of each page component when switching language manually:

1. On `nuxtServerInit()` I fetched some API data for all routes (e.g.
   site title, list of main pages for the navbar, etc.)
2. On `fetch()` in the page components I fetched needed resources
   **only if** these were not already in the nuxt store. This would make sense imho in a SSR/SPA site, because you don't need to fetch (and wait), if you already have the data.

Consequently, this means nuxt `generate` fetches this data **for each** page with `nuxtServerInit()` saving the payload associated with `nuxtServerInit`. However, it does **not** save the payload on `fetch()` because the if condition in the page component's `fetch()` method **at the time of generation** returns false - because the data was fetched already with `nuxtServerinit()`.

As a result, switching the locale on the generated static site triggered the simulated `fetch()` for the routes page component, but the payload for this method didn't contain the data.

**Solution**

The simplest solution is to not fetch any or at least any locale-specific data on `nuxtServerInit()` if `isStatic` is true and do the fetching in page or layout components.